# Disabling the youtube icon on the YouTubeStandalonePlayer in android?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I just wanted to know how to disable the youtube icon that comes in the `YouTubeStandalonePlayer`. Is it possible?
I don't want to take the user to youtube on clicking the icon. Is there any way to disable the youtube icon?

The below is the code how I am playing the the video using the `YouTubeStandalonePlayer`.

```
String videoId = getVideoId(cardsInfo.getCard_video_url());
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.android_key), videoId, 0, true, false);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Did you try YoutubePlayerView with CHROMELESS PlayerStyle and original controller of player?   https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView?hl=ja

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer), you can't.

But, you can try and use the other (not standalone) classes, which might give you better control [as suggested](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary) in the docs: `There are two ways to play videos. The first option is to place a YouTubePlayerFragment or YouTubePlayerView in your View hierarchy and then use the YouTubePlayer to control video playback in the View. **This gives a fine control of the experience**.` If they don't let it, you could atleast have better control of the flow/UI-visibility because you are controling the Activity (in contrast of giving the control to the standalone activity)